# Should I use strongly or forcefully in this context?

Tags: word-request

Consider these expressions

> You have to shut the door **strongly/forcefully** to lock it.
>
> You have to press the lid **strongly/forcefully/powerfully** to lock the jar.

I would like to know if any of these **strongly/forcefully/powerfully** is appropriate in this context? If not what word should I use instead of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both of these examples, *forcefully* is appropriate.  The other two choices sound strange to me.

*Forcefully* does sounds a bit formal, though.  In situations like these, I'm more likely to use informal phrases like *pretty hard* or *kinda hard*:

> You have to shut the door **pretty hard** to lock it.
>
> You have to press the lid **pretty hard** to close the jar.

Although some jars do have locking lids, I think it sounds strange to use the phrase *lock the jar*.  I might use a phrase like *to get the jar to close*.